# Accessing Props after render in multi level component tree - React

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

I'm somewhat new with React and am running into an issue where I am getting undefined props in components, child components and grandchild.

Here's what I have going on...

app.jsx

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    entities: [],
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get(`api.com`)
  .then(response => {this.setState({entities: response,})});
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Component entities={this.state.entities} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

From my understanding, once the component has mounted, it executes the axios call, and sets state.  I am then passing the state.entities into the Component.

I then need to access the props prior to the Component rendering, so am I doing that in componentWillMount(), and then setting the Component state to pass down as props to a ChildComponent?

```
componentWillMount() {
    var getEntities = this.props.entities
    this.setState({entities:getEntities})
  }

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent entities={this.state.entities} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the end, my issue is in my ChildComponent, or GrandChildComponent everything is rendering prior to and props or state being set.  So when I call {entities.id} I get an undefined.

Maybe I'm just dumb?

Comment: Is "entities" an object or an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) life cycle.

When you set state in Parent component in [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount),it re-render the child,grandchild component.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

        if(nextProps.entities){

           this.setState({entities:nextProps.entities})
        }
    }
```

[`componentWillMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) is called only on initial rendering and not for every re-rendering.In your case,you need to handle re-rendering .

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good to me. The only problem i see - is you pass props explicitly into Child component without checking it. While you data is fetching - `states` equal to `[]` and you pass it into child component.
I would add boolean state e.g `isFetched` and when your request is done set it to true. While data is fetching you can show `loading`. Example below.

```
state = {
  entities: [],
  isFetched: false
}
...
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get(`api.com`)
   .then(response => {this.setState({entities: response, isFetched: true})});
}
...
render(){
  const {isFetched, entities} = this.state
  return (
    <div>{isFetched ? <ChildComponent {entities}> : 'Loading...'}</div>
  )
}

const ChildComponent = ({entities}) => (<div>{JSON.stringify(entities)}</div>)
```

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting state with the response. You may/should set state with the data which is from the `API` side.

In `componentWillMount()`, you have to get the data and set the state with data parameter, not wet the response.

```
componentWillMount() {
  axios.get(`api.com`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => this.setState({entities: data}))
}
```

You can always perform `console.log()` before setting state.

```
componentWillMount() {
  axios.get(`api.com`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log('this is entities data', data))
}
```

Hope, this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

`network request` is `async` so `setState` inside `network request` will not be called when the component is mounting. so initially `this.state.entities` will be equal to `[]`. so `[].id` ie:(entities.id) is rerturning `undefined`.

initially set `entities` as `null`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    entities: null;,
  }
}
```

and access `entities.id` as

`entities ? entities.id : somethingElse`